# How do I find the intersection of 2 sets in my logfile (using LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

At my workplace I have a simplified log file of who has IM'ed (instant messaged) who.  For our simple example, let's pretend the log is a text file that consists of 2 tab-delimited columns.  If person A IM'ed person B, or vice versa, it shows up in the log as AB or BA.  The direction of the IM doesn't matter, just that the pair has been in contact with each other.

I have a list of 2 research groups, X and Y, which contains the names of people like A, B, C, etc.  My goal is to find out who in groups X and Y have IM'ed each other by looking at the log file.  I can't make any assumptions about the members of groups X and Y in terms of quantity of people or distinct members.

If this were a database I'd imagine using joins, but I'd like to learn how to do this with C#/LINQ.  How do I find the intersection of Group X and Group Y inside of the logfile?

I think I want to unite the members of lstGroupX and lstGroupY such that it looks like AB or BA for all possible 1-to-1 combinations between its members, and then look for AB or BA in the logfile.

```
//assume the log is in a list called lstLog
//a list called lstGroupX contains the names GroupX members
//a list called lstGroupY contains the names GroupY members

var IMBuddies = lstLog.Intersect(lstGroupX).Intersect(lstGroupY);
```

I don't think the above line is quite right.  What I really want is something like this

```
var IMBuddies = lstLog.Intersect(all possible permutations where lstGroupX members contacts lstGroupY members and vice versa)
```

but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: C#/LINQ *do* have [joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the job done:

```
var IMBuddies = lstLog.FindAll(x => 
                                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstGroupX.Find(y => x.Contains(y))) && 
                                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstGroupY.Find(y => x.Contains(y)))
);
```

This can be broken down into 3 parts, the condition that we are putting on lstLog, the condition we are putting on lstGroupY, and the condition we are putting on lstGroupX.  The lamda expression should read something like x => condition x must meet (i.e x => x.Id == 1 would get the elements that have an Id of 1).

**Condition for lstLog:**

```
    lstLog.FindAll(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(<return element of lstGroupY condition>) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(<return element of lstGroupX condition>))
```

In a nutshell, it asks for all the elements that doesn't return null from the lstGroupX condition and doesn't return null from the lstGroupY condition

**Condition for lstGroupX:**

```
    lstGroupX.Find(y=> x.Contains(y))
```

This takes each element in lstGroupX, and checks to see if the current element for the lstLog condition contains that element.  So, if x represents "AB" in lstLog and y represents "B" in lstGroupX, this is checking if "AB" contains "B".  If it does, then it returns "B".  If no elements are found, then it should return null (thus the reason !string.IsNullOrEmpty is added in there).

**Condition for lstGroupY:**

```
    lstGroupY.Find(y=> x.Contains(y))
```

This does the same thing as the condition for lstGroupX, with the exception that it is looking at the elements in lstGroupY instead.

Putting Them Together:

So, the putting all the conditions together, it basically looks at each element in lstLog, and if an element in lstGroupX is contained inside the lstLog element AND if an element in lstGroupY is contained inside the lstLog element, it will be added to the return set.

It should be noted that the FindAll method returns an IEnumerable, while Find method will stop once it finds the first one.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your help.  It's really dense and I'm having trouble parsing/un-packing the statement.  I think you're using a new thing I'm not familiar with..lambda expressions?  Can you help me understand what this does "!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstGroupY.Find(y => x.Contains(y))));"

Comment: I updated the answer to include breaking it down alittle. HTH